# Python Comma between line of code

Tags: python, comma-operator

I want to understand what does the comma do between self.data and self.next = data. Thanks

```
class Node(object):
  def __init__(self, data, nxt = None):
    self.data, self.next = data, nxt
class Context(object):
  def __init__(self, source, dest):
    self.source, self.dest = source, dest
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This

```
self.source, self.dest = source, dest
```

Does this

```
self.source = source
self.dest = dest
```

It is just a multivariable definition on a single line